# Create superuser error, TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: django, django-models, superuser

When i run createsuperuser command in terminal ..it prompts to enter email and then password .I didn't get the username field. After entering password it gives me TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Realtor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    top_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_hired = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this is the error :
`self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser( TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

Could anyone please guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: The posted database model is not related to the problem!

Comment: can you please elaborate, I didn't get it. @MohamedHamza

Comment: Your `Realtor` model does not have any relationship with the default user model in Django, based on that, there is not any problem with `Realtor` model, and I guess you  need to custom the default user model